# Prove that for any positive number $n$, $f(x)=[(x+2)^n-(x+1)^n+1](1-x)^n -2^n$ is an odd function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions, polynomials

Please help me prove that

$$f(x)=[(x+2)^n-(x+1)^n+1](1-x)^n -2^n$$

is an odd function.

Comment: If you think it's true, I'd try breaking it up into cases of $n$ even vs $n$ odd.

Comment: @userSeventeen  but this may be complicated. Do we have some other methods?

Comment: It is not an odd function in general, try [$n=4$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+((x%2B2)%5E4-(x%2B1)%5E4%2B1)(1-x)%5E4-2%5E4) for example.

Comment: @dxiv thank you for your answer. i have to apologize to everyone that i have posted a wrong problem. i tried n=1, 2, 3 at first and believed it could be true and thought it was a nice problem, but find it does not work when n≥4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f_{n}(x) = \left(-(x+1)^n+(x+2)^n+1\right) (1-x)^n-2^n
$$

Note the **counter example of @dxiv:**

[image: polys]

$$
%
\begin{align}
%
  f_{1}(x) & = -2 x\\[3pt]
%
  f_{2}(x) & = 2 x^3-6 x\\[3pt]
%
  f_{3}(x) & = -3 x^5+10 x^3-15 x\\[3pt]
%
  f_{4}(x) & = -36 x + \color{red}{2 x^2} + 36 x^3 - \color{red}{4 x^4} - 20 x^5 + \color{red}{2 x^6} + 4 x^7\\
%
\end{align}
%
$$

The $\color{red}{red}$ terms are *even* functions which destroy the odd symmetry.